# Create array with same length

Tags: arrays, rust, compile-time

I'm writing something that's writing images with lodepng-rust, and I'd like to work with pixels instead of `u8`s. I've created a struct

```
struct Pixel {r: u8, g: u8, b: u8}
```

and am building an array of `u8`s out of the elements of the array. Since I'm making the array by hand right now, I'm in the strange situation of needing to make the other array by hand as well. Is there a way I can create an array that's three times the length of the pixel array at compile time? Something like

```
let data: [u8; other_array.len()*3];
```

Which doesn't work because `.len()` isn't a compile time constant. The runtime cost doesn't really matter to me in this case, but if I could have the sizes related it would feel cleaner (and I might need the performance in the future).

**Edit:**
The solution I'm using is based on Levans's answer. **For people not initializing your array by hand, just follow Levans.** I initialize my first array by hand, but set the type to use the length specified in `pixel_count` so that it'll catch the wrong `pixel_count` at compile time. I create the second array with that constant, and then assert that the lengths have the right ratio. My minimal example looks like this:

```
struct Pixel {r: u8, g: u8, b: u8}
const pixel_count: usize = 4;

fn main() {
    let pixel_data = [Pixel; pixel_count] = [
        Pixel {r: 255, g: 0, b: 0},
        Pixel {r: 0, g: 255, b: 0},
        Pixel {r: 0, g: 0, b: 255},
        Pixel {r: 0, g: 99, b: 99},
    ];
    let mut data = [0u8; pixel_count*3];
    assert_eq!(pixel_data.len()*3, data.len());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way for you to create size-related arrays would be to store the initial size as a `const` item : they are compile-time constants :

```
const pixel_count: uint = 42;

struct Pixel { r: u8, g: u8, b: u8 }

fn main() {
    let pixels = [Pixel { r: 0, g: 0, b: 0 }, ..pixel_count];
    let raw_data = [0u8, ..pixel_count * 3];
    assert!(pixels.len() * 3 == raw_data.len());
}
```

Comment: You might want to make `pixel_number` into `pixel_count` so that they match.
Anyway, using the `assert!` makes the method I'm using perfect, thanks!

Comment: This no longer works in 0.12.0. Do you know if that is intentional?

Comment: @DrYap Indeed, it has changed, the keyword is now `const`. Thanks !